# How to change the product name in the login page?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

My question is about changing the product name in the login page of alfresco share (Version 5.2).
Actually, I did change the colors and size of the text, but I wasn't able to locate the html file that can let me change what it's important to me!
In the browser, I can see the code source of the page in the inspect elemnt. However, I can't access to it locally.

Please, tell me how to locate the file in the local server or if you know the path.

This is the code source in the inspect element :

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to edit **app.name** and **app.community** properties under opt/alfresco/tomcat/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/messages/slingshot*.properties

In the file slingshot.properties and slingshot_XX.properties, where XX is you language.

```
app.name = Custom Name
app.tagline = Alfresco Content Services
app.community = Custom Name
```

Override it as suggested [Overriding the default message bundle](https://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/kb-preset-internationalization.html)